# Question about asking general questions

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, questions, specific-question

I have recently posted a [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1469342/haunted-computer-windows-alternatives-to-quick-fixes-in-ubuntu) on ask ubuntu. However, that question was not about a problem that I am currently facing but about something I have faced before and that could happen again. This problem keeps happening to me because of my habit of installing and trying out lots of programs for fun. But this is not the kind of problem that can be solved with a single method you have to try out different ways to solve this problem with different commands. You will understand it if you read my question.

> When windows start slowing down or face any kind of problems, that can
> be fixed by using CHKDSK, DISM or SFC. If none of that works, we can
> just RESET the pc. Can you give me a list of command to get similar
> results on Linux.
>
> That is everything that can be done when your pc is acting haunted.
> What are some first aid that can be done when you experience this?
>
> NOTE: currently I am not facing any issue. whenever I face any issue,
> I just do a clean install which is not very efficient. I want to know
> what I can do the next time this happens. I am looking for everything
> that can be done including the alternatives for the three commands
> mentioned above and also steps to achieve similar results as doing a
> RESET.

This question is more of a general problem that you may face and does not have a one specific single method to solve. What I am expecting for an answer is some commands that I can tryout that may fix these general problems that I face in ubuntu the same way I can fix general problems I face in windows with commands like CHKDSK or by a RESET.

Some users have pointed out that when I post a question it has to be a specific problem that I am facing. I don't know what to do is there any way to improve my question, should I delete the question or is a general question like this even valid on stack exchange?

This is my question on ask ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1469342/haunted-computer-windows-alternatives-to-quick-fixes-in-ubuntu

Comment: "*Some users have pointed out that when I post a question it has to be a specific problem*." I see no such comments in your question. A specific problem is not required. A specific problem is more likely to attract useful answers, and this prediction came true: Your general question attracted no useful answers. Your frustration is a *consequence* of asking a question allowed but ill-suited to the venue.

Comment: @user535733 check the comments. There are two comments to be exact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I personally agree with the feedback you have received regarding your question.

The style of Ask Ubuntu (or any other Stack Exchange site) is a Q&A where a question should be about a specific problem, and answers should be objectively direct (as opposed to opinionated ones or answers that request more details, etc.). Open-ended questions that can generate a lot of answers usually end up getting closed. It is somewhat a similar reason why software recommendation questions are often closed if they don't offer enough information.

However, your type of question is fit more in a forum-style website, as they generate a lot back of and forth discussions (as evidenced by the number of comments you received on your question). I recommend using the [Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/) for such questions.

Comment: What you said makes sense. The question is more suited for a forum. I will post the question on the ubuntu forums. Thanks.